# Lotus Web issue with browser

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotus

I have been using display.none, for the hid-whens for example, all the hidden fields were kept in a section and section was hidden from web by using Display.none.

This is working for Internet Explorer till IE 9, but for IE 10 all the hidden fields are shown.

Can anyone help in this matter. Any alternative or approach.

Comment: Post sample snippet of html generated for your section. Also check if html differs for different browser versions.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing the page it sis very difficult to guess.

- Try validating the html through one of the many online html validators as something may not be closed or Notes might have given you an unwanted code addition .
- Try adding a background color to the css #wrapper to make sure the css is being called.
- Take a copy of the form and start removing all other elements one section at a time to see if something else is causing the issue.
- Add {meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=10;IE=9; IE=8; IE=7; IE=EDGE" /} as the very top meta tag and see if that fixes it. Replace the curly braces obviously.

All the best in finding the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like just the section element is getting hidden. Without seeing the code I can't tell why that changes between ie 9 and 10 but ie is famous for having varying behavior between versions.

One alternative that comes to mind: You could wrap the section and the fields in a DIV element using pass thru HTML and set that div's style to display:none.  That is pretty standard and should work across browsers.

Update: To give you an idea what I'm talking about, check out this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FhEun/1/).

HTML:

```
<form>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <input type="text" name="Field 1" /><br />
        <input type="text" name="Field 2" /><br />
        <input type="text" name="Field 3" />
    </div>

    <span>Some text that won't be hidden.</span>
</form>
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper {
    #display:none;
}
```

You can remove the # next to the display:none and see the difference, even in IE 10.

You'll need to look closely at the HTML being rendered by Domino and make sure that in fact all the fields you are trying to hide are surrounded by the DIV that is hidden.

Comment: I am doing exactly the same thing, making all the fields into a div tag and then making that div, as display none, Problem is that it is working in IE 7, 8,9 but in 10 it is failing, even in Mozilla and Chrome.